# Swift xcode two errors: Cannot assign value of type 'ShapeType' to type "ShapeButton.ShapeType"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to create an app that has a table and if you select one row you can create a text editor and an image, then save it, then go back to another row and save a different text/image.

EDIT: If you need more classes/information for me to put on stackoverflow, please let me know.

Error:
[image]

Entire project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8qwmh6mluqqcid/SwiftXcodeProjectTwoErrors.zip?dl=0

Class containing error:

```
import UIKit

weak var FirstFileNameTextField: UILabel!
enum ShapeType: String
{
    case Line = "Line"
    case Ellipse = "Ellipse"
    case Rectangle = "Rectangle"
    case FilledEllipse = "Filled Ellipse"
    case FilledRectangle = "Filled Rectangle"
    case Scribble = "Scribble"
}
let shapes: [ShapeType] = [ .Line, .Ellipse, .Rectangle, .FilledEllipse, .FilledRectangle, .Scribble ]

class MainProjectScene: UIViewController
{
    var row: Row?

    @IBAction func PressedSaveAs(sender: UIButton) //this is the save as function that I would like to know how to change
    {
        //1. Create the alert controller.
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Name/rename your file:", message: "Enter a filename to name/rename and save your file", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        //2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in
            textField.text = "Your file name"
        })

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler:
            {
                (action) -> Void in
                let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
                print("Text field: \(textField.text)")
                // rows.cell.textLabel?.text = textField.text
                CurrentFileName = textField.text!
                rows[IndexPath.row].FileName = textField.text!
                rows[IndexPath.row].UserText = self.TextUserScrollEdit.text!
        }))

        // 4. Present the alert.
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

      //  rows[indexPath.row].FileName = rows.cell.textLabel?.text
       // rows[i] = textField.text
               // if let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? MainProjectScene {
              //  if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {
              //  if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
               // detailViewController.row = rows[indexPath.row]
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        if let r = row
        {
            row!.FileName = r.FileName
            row!.QuartzImage = r.QuartzImage
            row!.UserText = r.UserText
            rows[IndexPath.row].UserText = self.TextUserScrollEdit.text!
        }
    }

    override func  viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        TextUserScrollEdit.text = rows[IndexPath.row].UserText
        // FacebookButton.addTarget(self, action: "didTapFacebook", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var TextUserScrollEdit: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var NewFileButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var TwoDQuartzButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var YouTubeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var TwitterButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var OpenFileButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var SnapChatButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var FacebookButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func PressedTwoDQuartzButton(sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBAction func PressedSnapchatButton(sender: UIButton){
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.snapchat.com/")!)
    }

    @IBAction func PressedYouTubeButton(sender: UIButton) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/")!)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var InstagramButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func PressedFacebookButton(sender: UIButton) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.facebook.com")!)
    }
    @IBAction func PressedInstagramButton(sender: UIButton) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.instagram.com/")!)
    }

    @IBAction func PressedTwitterButton(sender: UIButton) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://twitter.com/")!)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var SaveAsButton: UIButton!
    // @IBOutlet weak var shapeButton: ShapeButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var canvas: CanvasView!
    @IBOutlet var colorButtons: [UIButton]!
    @IBOutlet weak var shapeButton: ShapeButton!

        @IBAction func selectColor(sender: UIButton) {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0,
                usingSpringWithDamping: CGFloat(0.25),
                initialSpringVelocity: CGFloat(0.25),
                options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
                    for button in self.colorButtons {
                        button.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - 58
                    }
                    sender.frame.origin.y -= 20
                }, completion: nil)
            canvas.color = sender.backgroundColor!
            shapeButton.color = sender.backgroundColor!
        }

        @IBAction func selectShape(sender: ShapeButton) {
            let title = "Select Shape"
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

            for shape in shapes {
                let action = UIAlertAction(title: shape.rawValue, style: .Default) { action in
                    sender.shape = shape
                    self.canvas.shape = shape
                }
                alertController.addAction(action)
            }
            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

Comment: Still trying to answer this question but so far no answers, thank for removing the spaces though that helps for readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `enum ShapeType` declarations inside both `ShapeButton.swift` and `CanvasView.swift` files. You declare this type for several times. That's the reason.